# How to get position of each tag in a tags array using Jquery

Tags: jquery

When you use `$('body').children('input[type="text"]')`, if there are several input text fields in form, the return value must be an array of tag elements.

Then, I am going to get the position value on chrome window with respect to each element.

I just tried `$('form').children('input[type="text"]')[0].position();`
but it doesn't work, error is like this:

[image]

Comment: Try `form.find(...` instead of `form.children(...` it's unlikely they're directly in the form and not in some sort of layout div

Comment: `$(selector)[0]` will give you a DOM node, so `.position()` will not work - but you would get `.position is not a function` and should use `.eq(0)`.  But as you're getting `undefined` your `selector` is not finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
$('form').find('input[type=text]').eq(0).position();
```

Answer (score 1):

The position function returns padding, or if you have applied a position for the element with CSS, but I think that's not what you are searching for you want to get the order not the position.

First there is an error in your jQuery code. In jQuery when you want to call first children you don't do it like JavaScript you should do it like below:

```
$('input[type="text"]').first().position();
```

Second, if you want to get the order of the inputs you should consider a javascript for loop to loop on all inputs and you can get each value with index.

Third, If the number of inputs you have in the form isn't too many like 9 or 10 inputs, then I would recommend using id attribute instead of calling text call each input by its ID like below:

```
$("#first_element").position();
```